# Create loop in ModelBuilder in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, feature-class, iterator, loop

I am using the ModelBuilder to apply some analysis on some feature classes(shape files). I have to apply the same model for different feature classes and of course the output naming would be according to the input data naming.I would like to know whether it is possible to define a loop in ModelBuilder to apply the model over a group of shapefiles and differentiate it based on the input data name.

I have heard that there is a possibility to use ArcPy to define loop but as I am not a pro in ArcPy , would rather to do it in ModelBuilder.

Comment: Can you clarify more what you mean by this, "differenciate it based on the input data name"?

Comment: you can do this with arcpy (python). export your model to a python snippet and use a 'for' loop to get all feature classes analysis. cant be more specific than that without seeing your model.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Iterate Feature Classes tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/examples-of-using-iterators-in-modelbuilder.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_46903073A36D4E928AAFC0F0AE5240EC) within ModelBuilder.  This will iterate through your feature classes as long as they are all within the same workspace.  It is a ModelBuilder only tool that can be accessed through the menu within ModelBuilder.